# Donations displayed together by year and month

Tags: php, mysql

I'm a newb to php and mysql. I hope that I have provided enough information below.

Table name Donations

```
|========================================================================|
|  username  | game | donation | month | year |      time_stamp     | id |
|========================================================================|
| TheSquatch | DayZ |    5     | June  | 2015 | 2015-06-11 00:17:46 | 1  |
|  TheMusic  | DayZ |    20    | July  | 2015 | 2015-07-10 03:20:46 | 2  |
| Sasquatch  | DayZ |    35    | July  | 2015 | 2015-07-10 03:26:04 | 3  |
|========================================================================|
```

Here is my current script.

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT username, game, donation, month, year, time_stamp, id FROM donations GROUP BY year, month ORDER BY id");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<center><b>" . ($row['3']) . " " . ($row['4']) . "</b></center>";
echo str_repeat("<center>" . ($row['0']) . " $" . ($row['2']) . " (" . ($row['1']) . ")<br></center>",1
);
}
```

The above code currently gives me the following results.

```
June 2015
TheSquatch $5 (DayZ)
July 2015
TheMusic $20 (DayZ)
```

I need it to give me the following result. (All donations in the month not just the first one.)

```
June 2015
TheSquatch $5 (DayZ)
July 2015
TheMusic $20 (DayZ)
Sasquatch $35 (DayZ)
```

If I remove "GROUP BY year, month" I get the following result.

```
June 2015
TheSquatch $5 (DayZ)
July 2015
TheMusic $20 (DayZ)
July 2015
Sasquatch $35 (DayZ)
```

Thanks in advance.

**--------------------------------------------------**

***Here is the final code that I used for the result I got below.***

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT username, game, donation, month, year, time_stamp, id FROM donations ORDER BY id");
$old_row = 'blank';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
if ($row['3'] . " " . $row['4'] != $old_row) {   
$old_row = ($row['3'] . " " . $row['4']); 
echo "<center><b>" . ($row['3']) . " " . ($row['4']) . "</b></center>";
}  
echo str_repeat("<center>" . ($row['0']) . " $" . ($row['2']) . " (" . ($row['1']) . ")<br></center>",1
);
}
```

***The result.***

```
June 2015
TheSquatch $5 (DayZ)
July 2015
TheMusic $20 (DayZ)
Sasquatch $35 (DayZ)
```

**--------------------------------------------------**

Comment: month and year columns are entirely redundant. Please remove.

Comment: @strawberry The month and year columns are input manually when submitting new content. The time_stamp is just for tracking the date and time the information was added.

Comment: OK. As to the answer to your question - are you sure you can't figure it out. It's kind of staring you in the face!

Comment: @Strawberry Some day I might see what your seeing but as for right now my knowledge of php is next to none. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: As you seem to have figured out for yourself, the query should be as follows: `SELECT username, game, donation, month, year, time_stamp, id FROM donations ORDER BY year, month, id;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
     $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT username, game, donation, month, year, time_stamp, id FROM donations  ORDER BY id");
  $old_row = 'blank';
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    if ($row['3'] . " " . $row['4'] != $old_row) {   
   $old_row = ($row['3'] . " " . $row['4']); 
    echo "<center><b>" . ($row['3']) . " " . ($row['4']) . "</b></center>";
   }  
  echo str_repeat("<center>" . ($row['0']) . " $" . ($row['2']) . " (" . ($row['1']) . ")<br></center>",1
    );
    }
```

Comment: That gives me the same result as removing "GROUP BY year, month".

Comment: Ahh sorry about that. The problem is in your PHP -- not your MySQL.

Comment: basically you need to add a check whether you are still in the same month / year in terms of your display formatting (which I've edited it to contain now).  The difference between the triple GROUP BY  and no GROUP BY is if someone has donated multiple times in a month.

Comment: Your updated version of my code worked perfectly after I removed "GROUP BY year, month". Thank you!